# Can't update value using reducer React JS after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I'm currently learning useReducer and try to convert useState to useReducer in todo app. My problem :

1. TOGGLE_TODO can't update the value when click.

```
// First try
case TOGGLE_TODO:
   let targetId = todoItem[action.index];
   let newTodo = [...todoItem];
   return (newTodo[targetId].completed = !newTodo[targetId].completed);

// Second try
case TOGGLE_TODO:
   return todoItem.map((todo, index) => {
       if (index === action.index) {
          return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
       }
       return todo;
});
```

```
<button
    value={index}
    onClick={(event) =>
       dispatch({
          type: TOGGLE_TODO,
          index: event.target.value,
       })
    }
 >
    {todo.completed ? "done" : "pending"}
 </button>
```

2. UPDATE_TODO, I have no clue for convert this to useReducer. Can I convert this too ? Here is my code using useState.

```
const onUpdate = (e) => {
   const target = e.currentTarget.value;
   const todoTarget = todoItem[target].name;
   setInput(todoTarget);
   setTodoIndex(target);
};
```

And here is my codesandbox for full code. [MY CODE USING USESTATE](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-zhukovsky-uygg3l?file=/src/App.js) and [MY CODE USING USEREDUCER](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-merkle-cujkl1?file=/src/App.js:725-908)

Comment: If you return an expression, It doesn't make sense.  U should alter the completed value first, then return the array, may it'll work.

Comment: @DeepShah I have another logic, but still same. return todoItem.map((todo, index) => {
               if (index === action.index) {
                  return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
               }
               return todo;
            });

Comment: Can you provide the whole code, so I can understand clearly, what's the problem?

Comment: @DeepShah I'm just try to convert all of my code from useState to useReducer. You can visit my full code in codesandbox.  I have mention it in my question

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: @jondoe I can't to update the value of completed when click the button. When using useState is working, but I try to convert to useReducer, and that's not work

Comment: I understand that, but what doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @jondoe Yap. cannot read properties of undefined completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you first TOGGLE_TODO handler if flawed -

```
// First try
case TOGGLE_TODO:
   let targetId = todoItem[action.index];
   let newTodo = [...todoItem];
   return (newTodo[targetId].completed = !newTodo[targetId].completed);
```

Your `todoAction` is actually a reducer and not an action, so you should rename it to `todoReducer`. Also, a reducer needs to return a new copy of the entire state, and not just change one part of it, so your second try is correct.

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
   return todoItem.map((todo, index) => {
       if (index === action.index) {
          return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
       }
       return todo;
});
```

Notice how in the first case you are returning one todoItem, where in the second case you are returning an entire new array.

The problem with the code is that in your button, when you dispatch the action with the value, you are dispatching a string -

```
<button
    value={index}
    onClick={(event) =>
       dispatch({
          type: TOGGLE_TODO,
          index: event.target.value,  // <- This is a string
       })
    }
 >
    {todo.completed ? "done" : "pending"}
 </button>
```

And in your reducer you are trying to compare it to a number -

```
if (index === action.index) // This will always be false since index is a .number and action.index is a string
```

The solution is to dispatch a number like so -

```
dispatch({
          type: TOGGLE_TODO,
          index: Number(event.target.value),
       })
```

working codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/long-monad-5yzjv7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: REALLY... I don't expect if the value is a string. And thanks for info that reducer need to return the entire of state. And for updating the todo item, how to achieve using reducer ?

Comment: Your second try is fine and works, you can check out the code sandbox i linked to see the working demo

Comment: I mean for updating  value of property name